# Command Line Number Line Not In Sync

Tags: linux, command-line, tail, head

I'm playing around with the command line. For some reason when I try to grab lines 439 - 445 the output I am getting is lines 375 - 381 instead. I use the tail command to jump to line 439 then use the head command to print only the next six lines. Those aren't the six lines I get as shown in the screenshots below.

```
kali > tail -n+439 /etc/snort/snort.conf | head -n 6
```

Screenshots: [grep grabbing wrong lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD10r.jpg)

[Lines 375 - 381](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ValWM.jpg)

What's the issue?

Comment: Please post text as text.

Comment: You are looking at a wrong excerpt, @Dre. The `WinXP` Character String that appears on the Line #445 does not appear on the Line #381. You must have bumped onto a similar excerpt.

Comment: Yea that's what Im sayin @DOBRESCU_Mihai

Comment: Something is wrong, @Dre, in relation to your expectations. The `grep` does not select a continuous excerpt of lines, while the `tail`-`head` combination does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nl` numbers *non-empty* lines by default. `head` or `tail` counts *all* lines.

Use `cat -n` (option not required by POSIX), `grep -n ''` or [`nl -b a -d ''`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nl.html) to number all lines.

Comment: The `nl` Line does not have anything to do with the  `tail` Line, @Kamil Maciorowski. We do not know why it is still presented to us on the output. And yes, you were absolutely right, we would really be helped if we could see the Text instead of the Photographs.